# Recursively iterate through directory - Linux

Tags: linux, recursion

I want to recursively loop through all subdirectories within the current directory.

```
for i in *
```

this only iterates through all the files in the current directory. How do you make it so that if the file it is looking at is a directory, to enter that directory and recursively look through that directory too and so on and so forth.

EDIT: sorry should have been more specific. i cant use ls -R, as i want to display it in a tree structure with a certain format type. I have heard there are commands which can do this but i have to use a loop. cannot use "find" either...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  If you are just trying to list files, `ls -R` should work.

Comment: Use an `if [ -d "$i" ]; then` to test if ${i} is a directory. You might also use `find . -type 'd'`

Comment: yes i've tried the if statement but it doesnt continue into deeper directories if it does find a directory. cant use find

Comment: Define a bash [function](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-script-function-examples/) and recurse with that `if`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about homework and seems to require writing a script to _recurse_ over the files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to do what you need.  Call it with `recp 0` in the current directory.

```
function recp
{
    lvl=$(($1 + 1))
    for f in *
    do
        j=0
        while [[ $j -lt $lvl ]]
        do
            echo -n "    "
            j=$(($j+1))
        done
        echo $f
        [[ -d $f ]] && ( cd $f && recp $lvl )
    done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good at bash scripting
but the example below goes through all the directories.
You can replace the echo command with whatever you like.
I'm sure the style of this example can be improved.

Also did you consider the command "tree"?

Good luck.

```
#!/bin/bash

function recursiveList
{
  if [ -d $1 ]
  then
      cd $1
      for x in *
      do
          recursiveList $x
      done
      cd ..
  else
      echo $1
  fi
}

for i in *
do
    recursiveList $i
done
```